# Regex for value inside mustache braces while ignoring erroneous whitespace

Tags: ruby, regex

I am currently attempting to use Regex to obtain the value inside Mustache syntax braces e.g

`Hello {{{ name }}}, {{{greeting}}}. what is your favourite code related website {{ code question website!!! ?? ? }}? here is some random fact {{ random fun  fact    }}`

I am trying to select everything except the braces and the leading and trailing white space (In the case the user adds more accidentally) or rather i would like to use groups to capture these 3 elements

- group 1: '{' and leading whitespace
- group 2: value we want
- group 3: trailing white space and '}'

so far i have come up with the following `({{2,3}\s*)([^{}]*)(\s*}{2,3})` but if you check the capture groups the 2nd group matches then value we want...Which is good, but also the trailing white space which should be in the third group. i.e

- group 1: '{' and leading whitespace
- group 2: value we want with trailing white space
- group 3: '}'

Ruby Implementation
`str.gsub(/({{2,3}\s*)([^{}]*)(\s*}{2,3})/) { |_| $~[1]+Base64.urlsafe_encode64($~[2].strip, padding: false)+$~[3] }`

Comment: Do not include links to external websites when you can easily copy and paste the content from those sites into your question. When that link stops working no one will be able to see the work you’ve done. It’s _32 characters_ in a _single line_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to `scan` your input string into an array matches, using the following pattern:

```
\{+\s*([^{}]+)\s*\}+
```

This would capture all content appearing in between (presumably) nested sets of curly braces.  Then, we can flatten that array into a single level array of string matches, from the single capture group, and collect, removing leading and trailing whitespace.

```
str = "Hello {{{ name }}}, {{{greeting}}}. what is your favourite code related website {{ code question website!!! ?? ? }}? here is some random fact {{ random fun  fact    }}"
arr = str.scan(/\{+\s*([^{}]+)\s*\}+/)
print arr.flatten.collect{|x| x.strip || x }

["name", "greeting", "code question website!!! ?? ?", "random fun  fact"]
```

Comment: That is useful, but the end result I'm looking for is to also have the original string while matching the aforementioned characters and modifying/replacing them with base64 encoded versions of the tag.

i am currently using gsub `gsub(/({{2,3}\s*)([^{}]*)(\s*}{2,3})/) { |_| $~[1]+Base64.urlsafe_encode64($~[2].strip, padding: false)+$~[3] }`

Comment: Well that isn't what your question says, and you should not change your question after others have already answered.

Comment: @Genhain Why would you post a question that isn't your actual question? I recommend you read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and remember that you're asking _volunteers_ to help you.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen and anothermh. Thank you for your time, sorry i was not succinct enough.

Comment: Ask a new question and reference this one, and maybe use my pattern if that would help at all.

Comment: I think i came up with what i need, a more rigorous testing is needed but it seems to achieve what i want, rest assured if it does not i will be making a much more concise inquiry. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "Hello {{{ name }}}, {{{greeting}}}. what is your favourite code related website {{ code question website!!! ?? ? }}? here is some random fact {{ random fun  fact    }}"
```

```
r = /
    {+[ ]*     # match 1+ left braces then 0+ spaces
    \K         # forget everything matched so far
    .+?        # match 1+ characters, lazily
    (?=[ ]*})  # match 0+ spaces then 1 right brace in a positive lookahead
    /x

str.scan(r)
  #=> ["name", "greeting", "code question website!!! ?? ?", "random fun  fact"]
```

This regular expression is conventionally written:

```
/{+ *\K.+?(?= *})/
```

In free-spacing mode spaces are stripped out before the expression is parsed, so spaces that are part of the expression must be protected. I have done so by putting them in a character class. Alternatively, spaces can be escaped. Depending on requirements, one could instead match whitespaces with `\s`, `[[:space:]]` or `\p{Space}`, or spaces or tabs with `[[:blank:]]` or `\p{Blank}`.